# How to get total from another table

Tags: php, sql

I'm a newbie. I have this project, I have two tables:

Sales Table

```
id     ShipDate     ShipAddress      PONumber      TotalCans
23     03/04/2016   Washington       12345         39
```

Sales Details Table

```
id     SalesID      ProductName     LotCode       Cans
01     23           Cherry          CBK111        12
02     23           Cherry          CBK112        24
03     23           Cherry          CBK114         3
```

I would like to get the sum of `cans` and reflect it to the field `totalcans`. Im using PHP and SQL.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `SELECT SUM(cans) AS totalcans FROM table WHERE ?`  the `?` = You haven't given enough information to answer.

Comment: You could start looking at this on the `SUM()` aggregate function http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sum/ and read up on JOINS http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/

Comment: @loner14, what have you tried on your own? Add that to your question so we can best help you from there.

Comment: Please make your question clear and tell in details.

Comment: Based on what you're saying, I think "Sales Table" is a summary table, and you're asking how to update it with the details of "Sales Details Table"?

Comment: so the setup is table "Sales" is the parent and table "SalesDetails is the child. so i would like the field "totalcans" keep updating everytime i add another entry under salesdetails.

Comment: right now i created an ajax-total-sales.php. $id = intval($_REQUEST['id']);
 if(!$id) exit;
 
 $TotalJars = sqlValue("SELECT sum(Jars) from salesdetails;
 $TotalCases = sqlValue("SELECT sum(Cases) from salesdetails;

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the sales details by sales ID getting the sum of cans per sales ID and join the result with sales.

```
SELECT s.id sales_id,
       s.totalcans sales_total_cans,
       x.sum_of_cans sales_details_sum_of_cans
       FROM sales s
            INNER JOIN (SELECT sd.salesid,
                               sum(sd.cans) sum_of_cans
                               FROM sales_details sd
                               GROUP BY sd.salesid) x
                       ON x.salesid = s.id;
```